# What is the difference between Document and Value in rapidjson?

Tags: rapidjson

Seems Document can also be used as parameter in

```
void test(Value value);
```

and both Document and Value can have child value, what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 14):

Firstly, the `test` function should not compile because `Value` does not support copy constructor. So you must use `Value& value` or `const Value& value)` instead.

Back to the question, `Value` represents a node in the DOM. `Document` derives from `Value`, and it represents the root of the DOM. `Document` provides functionality for parsing a JSON into the DOM, while `Value` cannot.

If the function does not need to call APIs dedicated for `Document`, such as `Document::Parse()`, you should use `Value&`. Passing a `Document` object to `Value&` parameter is OK in C++ too.

Comment: Could you pls explain what do you mean by saying should use `Value&`, is there any shortage if I use `Document` instead of `Value`?